# Using Previous Value In jquery .load data refresh

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

So I've got a data table that is updated with two different sets of buttons. The jquery is thus;

```
$('body').on('click', "button", function () {
    var $but_name = $(this).attr("name");
    var $but_id = $(this).attr("id");
    if($but_name==="sky_week") {
      $("#adv_stats").load("index.php #adv_stats", {this_week:$but_id});
    } else if($but_name==="ASC") {
      $("#adv_stats").load("index.php #adv_stats", {up_down_type:"ASC",sort_type:$but_id});
    } else if($but_name==="DESC") {
      $("#adv_stats").load("index.php #adv_stats", {up_down_type:"DESC",sort_type:$but_id});
    }
  });
```

It literally just grabs the id of the button clicked and passes what was clicked to the load to refresh the data table.

*(On an unrelated note, I'm new to jquery but I've got my load pointing at itself. So index.php is the page the code is on and I've just got it pointing at a div lower down to update that. It works  - and shouldn't get stuck on an infinite loop because it's only triggered on clicks - but I feel like it's wrong and bad coding. Can someone confirm or deny this?)*

The issue I have is that when you click the ASC or DESC buttons, it doesn't pull the week through because that's on a different button. I think it's because of the PHP at the top of the page that pulls it;

```
  $this_week = $_POST['this_week'] ?? '202118';
  $up_down = $_POST['up_down_type'] ?? 'ASC';
  $sort = $_POST['sort_type'] ?? 'nt_login';
  $breakdown = get_adv_breakdown($this_week, $sort, $up_down);
```

And it's because of the '?? '202118' bit, which is defaulting to 202118 as the week instead of the currently selected week.

How do I get it to update the ASC values and keep the currently selected week? I feel like I need to somehow store the week somewhere else, but this is hitting the limit of my jquery knowledge.

Here's a visual of the final page, showing the two different sets of buttons;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU8Kd.png

I've added the html that generates the buttons;

```
<td align="center">Advisor<button name="ASC" id="nt_login"><i class="arrow up"></i></button><button name="DESC" id="nt_login"><i class="arrow down"></button></td>
etc
etc
```

And a little loop that adds the last 12 weeks;

```
<div id="week-buttons">
  <p align="center"><?php foreach($no_weeks as $week) { ?>
    <button name="sky_week" class="sky-primary-button w-button" id='<?php echo h($week['Week']); ?>' onclick="this.blur();">
      <?php echo h($week['Week']); ?>
    </button>
  <?php } ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are reloading your page whenever you do a sort. In order to preserve the value of `$this_week` you will need to pass that as a `$_POST` value to your page when you fire `.load()`

It should be as simple as doing something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', "button", function () {
    var $but_name = $(this).attr("name");
    var $but_id = $(this).attr("id");
    if($but_name==="sky_week") {
        $("#adv_stats").load("index.php #adv_stats", {this_week:$but_id}); // this seems to be an error?
    } else if($but_name==="ASC") {
        $("#adv_stats").load("index.php #adv_stats", {up_down_type:"ASC",sort_type:$but_id, this_week: $this_week});
    } else if($but_name==="DESC") {
        $("#adv_stats").load("index.php #adv_stats", {up_down_type:"DESC",sort_type:$but_id, this_week: $this_week});
    }
});
```

Comment: There are two sets of buttons - the sort buttons and the week buttons - so you'd only ever click one of them. Which is fine when you click the week button, but when you click a sort button, it doesn't have a week associated with it to pass through. I'm trying to work out how to pass a week value through if it's not been selected as part of the click function.

Comment: You should share the html portion for the button groups

Comment: I've added this to the original post. Cheers!